Embedded image in Excel document displaying as #UNKOWN! when opened in GitHub Action from a Chocolatey install
Problem
I'm trying to automate taking a screenshot of a region of an Excel file that is installed with Chocolatey using GitHub Actions running on Windows. Everything is working as expected, except Excel is not displaying the embedded image correctly on the Windows instance running inside the GitHub Action. Instead, it is displaying #UNKNOWN! in the cell where the image should be.
Example
What I expect is this:
A portion of the screenshot with the image correctly displayed in the cell

What I get is this:
A portion of the screenshot with the image incorrectly displayed as #UNKOWN! in the cell

Code
Here is a sample of job from the GitHub Action Workflow:
Note: Add-Excel-Trusted-Location.ps1 and export-png.py are scripts I wrote that have been tested and appear to be working both locally and, on the Windows instance running inside GitHub Actions.
Example ENV variables:
env:
  EXCEL_FILE_PATH: 'MySpreadsheet.xlsx'
  OUTPUT_PNG_PATH: 'MySpreadsheetScreenshot.png'
  INPUT_EQUIPMENT_SHEET_NAME: 'Sheet1'
  INPUT_EQUIPMENT_CELL_RANGE: '$$A$$3:$$I$$35'

Example GitHub Action Job
  name: Export image from Excel spreadsheet
  runs-on: windows-latest
  steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Install Office
      run: choco install office365business --params "'/productid:ExcelRetail /updates:FALSE'"

    - name: Add Excel Trusted Location
      run: pwsh .github/workflows/lib/Add-Excel-Trusted-Location.ps1 -Path "${{ env.EXCEL_FILE_PATH }}"

    - name: Setup Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v5
      with:
        python-version: '3.12.3'

    - name: Install Python dependencies
      run: pip install pywin32 ImageGrab pillow

    - name: Export PNG from Excel
      run: python .github/workflows/lib/export-png.py "${{ env.EXCEL_FILE_PATH }}" "${{ env.OUTPUT_PNG_PATH }}" "${{ env.INPUT_EQUIPMENT_SHEET_NAME }}" "${{ env.INPUT_EQUIPMENT_CELL_RANGE}}"

I've tried running this locally on my Windows 11 PC running Excel (Build 17830.20210 Click-to-Run). This all runs as expected, but my machine has an established installation of Excel.
I've also tried adding the file path to Excel's Trusted Locations registry key (HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\Trusted Locations), but that still shows #UNKOWN! in the target cell.

In your note, export-png.py is mentioned twice. Forgot to mention the other one?

Have you verified the CLI args of export-png.py script by validating them e.g. the image path?

@Azeem, sorry about the duplicate reference to export-png.py, copy/paste error.
I've verified the arguments. I'm getting a screenshot of the appropriate cell range. The only difference between testing this locally and running this on the Windows instance inside the GitHub Action is the latter does not display the image. My initial thought is it might be security related; where Excel does not want to display the image of an "untrusted" file, but I've not proved that out yet.

Sure, no worries. How do you verify it? Are you uploading the generated Excel file as an artifact?

It does get uploaded as an artifact. The workflow is in this repo: https://github.com/ThePerfectStrangers/TechnicalDocumentation/blob/main/.github/workflows/full-band-input-list-workflow.yml

Artifacts are different. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-what-your-workflow-does/storing-and-sharing-data-from-a-workflow for more details. Your workflow is committing back to the repo.

Just looked at the repo and the relevant files. The Excel file doesn't seem to have the image in it. I'm assuming that it should already be there. Where is it? Replaced by some past commit(s)? The export is being done from A3 to I35 (the range doesn't include the image). However, this range is not even being used by the Python script.

Good catch! I probably linked it instead of embedding it while I was debugging this issue. I fixed the image problem by properly embedding the .png inside of the spreadsheet. I confirmed it existed in the xl\media directory inside the .xlsx file. I re-ran the GitHub Action, but unfortunately I'm still seeing #UNKNOWN! in the cell where the image should be on the screenshot.

Right. Verified the xl/media and the file image1.png is indeed there. As it's an #UNKNOWN! error, it seems like a compatibility issue between versions of Excel. Could you please verify the version of your local instance and add it in your question? In GHA workflow runs, it's office365business v17830.20162.0 and that is the latest one available via choco i.e. Office 365 Business 17830.20162.

I'm running Excel Build 17830.20210 Click-to-Run, so I don't believe it's a compatibility issue. They both seem to be at the same major version.
I updated the OP with this info.

See this sample workflow and its respective run. Download the uploaded artifacts and verify. I created a sample.xlsx using LibreOffice Calc on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and added your logo in that. Also, updated your Input List/Full Band/Input List.xlsx file and updated the log in it too. Both files are converted to PNGs successfully. You may compare your export-png.py script with my workflow for some small changes (don't seem to be related the issue directly).

The issue seems to be with the input file itself. You need to verify that thoroughly. There's this https://github.com/glexey/excel2img project that converts Excel files to images. You might want to take a look at this and use it instead of your own script.

I stood up a Windows Server 2022 VM (similar to what is used in runs-on: windows-latest inside the GitHub Action) and worked through the GitHub Action workflow manually. The issue ended up being the version of Excel that was being installed by Chocolatey. This is the command I was using:
choco install office365business --params "'/productid:ExcelRetail /updates: FALSE'"
Note the productid, ExcelRetail. This was installing "Microsoft Excel 2016". This version of Excel did not have support for placing images in a cell, so I kept getting #UNKONWN! in the cell, just like I was previously observing in the output files from the GitHub Action runs.
To fix the issue, I changed the productid to O365HomePremRetail:
choco install office365business --params "'/productid:O365HomePremRetail /exclude: Access Groove Lync OneDrive OneNote Outlook Publisher Word Powerpoint /updates: FALSE /eula:TRUE'"
This command still only installs Excel, though it is harder to read due to all the exclusions I had to add in order to just get Excel and not the entire Office Suite. The resulting installation is a more modern version of Excel: "Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365". This version has support for placing images inside cells.
This updated version yielded the screen shot (and PDFs) of the Excel files just as I originally intended:

You can view the GitHub repository here:  https://github.com/ThePerfectStrangers/TechnicalDocumentation
You can view the fully functional GitHub Action workflow here:  https://github.com/ThePerfectStrangers/TechnicalDocumentation/blob/5d966a5f9b8640c72a08e761a026b6fe9edefbcd/.github/workflows/full-band-input-list-workflow.yml
